# Uneven space after last row of the grid inside listview in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working in xamarin.forms. I am facing the very silly issue and already wasted 5 hours on it. It's designing issue.

```
<Grid x:Name="MaingrdForms">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lstLatestProducts" HasUnevenRows="True"
                          ItemAppearing="LstLoadmore"
                          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                          Refreshing="LstPulled"
                          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <Grid Padding="10">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" 
                                               Source="{Binding ProductImg}" Margin="5" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProductName}" Style="{StaticResource LabelHeaderStyle}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProductDesc}" Style="{StaticResource LabelDescStyle}"/>
                                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Source="icon_password.png"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding SubscriptionCategory}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                            <Image Source="icon_password.png"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding CreatedDate}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalOptions="Start" Source="erecall.png"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lblNoRecordFound" Text="No Record found" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
```

**In List, I am taking HasUnevenRow=true to set row height but in every row, there is some space after the last row. the height of that space is also different. I can't figure out where is the actual issue.**

[image]

Comment: My guess is it's the StackLayout expanding to create the extra space but I'd suggest setting different background colors on the grid and views to figure out which control is causing the problem.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?